# creating a dictionary using a generator with format strings

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a data frame from a dictionary by looping over a list of string column names, rather than slicing the dataframe directly. For instance

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,7), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))

list_of_cols = ['A','B','C']

dictslice = {'%s': df['%s'] % (elt for elt in list_of_cols), 'Z': np.ones(len(df))}
```

But I cannot have a format string outside of a string so am not sure how to proceed. I do not want a solution like

```
df[[list_of_cols]]
```

since I want to add more vectors to dictslice that may not necessarily be in df.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
I am a fool, it works with this:

```
 dictslice = {'%s' % elt : df[elt] for elt in list_of_cols}
```

but this does not work:

```
 dictslice = {'%s' % elt : df[elt] for elt in list_of_cols, 'Z': np.ones(len(df))}
```

Comment: Why not simply do `dictslice = df.to_dict('series'); dictslice['Z'] = np.ones(len(df))`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that can be done with simple variable access.

What's wrong with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,7), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))

list_of_cols = ['A','B','C']

dictslice = dict([(elt, df[elt]) for elt in list_of_cols] + [('Z', np.ones(len(df)))])
```

Comment: I get the error: 'unsupported operand type(s)  for +: generator and tuple"

Comment: Right you are.  I just edited my answer, and think it should work now.